# Flutter social share plugin(facebook / instagram) not working

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, instagram, socialshare

I'm trying to make share function for my app to share image/video to facebook, instagram and etc.
So i got some plugins for that `social_share_plugin 0.3.1 + 1(for facebook and instagram)`, and
`share 0.6.5 + 4(for etc)`.
I use `getTemporaryDirectory()` for my flutter app root directory.
When I use `share` to use just share button, it works on facebook and instagram.
But, `social_share_plugin` not working with same path for parameter.
I implemented some codes to `manifest.xml` what social_share_plugin requires for successful working(also other codes too).
But i can't get why this not working.
This code is my sharing function for dialog.

```
switch(shareType) {
    case "SAVE":
        await saveWork(false); //save file to getTemporaryDirectory()
        break;
    case "SHARE":
        Share.shareFiles([widget.file_path]); //this works very well 
        break;
    case "FACEBOOK":
        var permission = await checkPermissions();
        if (permission.isGranted) {
            //this not working with same directory
            await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebook(path: widget.file_path).catchError(
                (e) => print("[facebook error]: " + e.toString())
            );
        } else {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "permission is denied");
        }
        break;
    case "INSTAGRAM":
        var permission = await checkPermissions();
        if (permission.isGranted) {
            //this not working with same directory
            await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedInstagram(path: widget.file_path).catchError(
                (e) => print("[insta error]: " + e.toString())
            );
        } else {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "permission is denied");
        }
        break;
    }
```

The share dialog works well when I clicked instagram share.
But in instagram app, toast message shows `Unable to load image` and come back to my app when i clicked "feed" to share.
Share to direct and story shows `Unable to share image`.

Also, even facebook share button not showing dialog.
My file path is like `/data/user/0/com.example.app/cache/save/1510196212_2-1609136165662.png`

Comment: Hi any updates regarding this issue. I also face this issue. I have created png file on "getTemporaryDirectory()" but with this "social_share" it is not loading. Although it is loading with "share" package. I'm using "2.0.5" version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to this https://pub.dev/packages/social_share this plugin. I'm using this plugin and working fine for me.

```
social_share: ^2.0.5
```

Comment: does it not support for share image or video to feed? it seems there's only share to story.

Comment: final file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                      source: ImageSource.gallery,
                    );
                    SocialShare.shareOptions(
                      file!.path,
                    ).then((file) {
                      print(file);
                    });   ||  how to share image and pdf files ?